# Rspec expectation triggering twice

Tags: rspec

Getting some odd behavior when testing a custom class in Rspec (version 3.9)

**Code**

```
class AlertMaster
    def initialize(params = {})
        ...
    end

    def send_alert
        1.upto(2) do |attempt|
            begin
                self.alert_me
                break
            rescue => e
                if attempt == 2
                    puts ">> here"
                    puts attempt
                    Rails.logger.fatal "Alert error - #{e.message}"
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**RSpec**

```
    describe "send_alert" do
        before do
            @at = AlertMaster.new
        end
        describe "catches appropriately" do
            describe "first time succeeds" do
                it "should not log error" do
                    expect(@at).to receive(:alert_me).and_return(true)
                    expect(Rails.logger).to_not receive(:fatal)

                    @at.send_alert
                end
            end

            describe "first time fails, second time succeeds" do
                it "should not log error" do
                    expect(@at).to receive(:alert_me).and_raise("oops")
                    expect(@at).to receive(:alert_me).and_return(true)
                    expect(Rails.logger).to_not receive(:fatal)

                    @at.send_alert
                end
            end

            ####### FAILING SPEC
            describe "first time fails, second time fails" do
                it "should log error" do
                    expect(@at).to receive(:alert_me).and_raise("oops")
                    expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:fatal).with("Alert error - oops")

                    @at.send_alert
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

The last spec fails because `Rails.logger` is called twice. Console log shows the `puts` statements I put in correctly only trigger on last attempt. Failing spec output:

```
>> here
2

...

Failure/Error: expect(@at).to receive(:alert_me).and_raise("oops")
     
       (#<AlertMaster:0x00007ffca7edd180 ...).alert_me(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 2 times with any arguments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The last spec fails because Rails.logger is called twice.

No, the last spec fails because `alert_me` is called twice but you only expected it to be called once.

```
Failure/Error: expect(@at).to receive(:alert_me).and_raise("oops")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     
       (#<AlertMaster:0x00007ffca7edd180 ...).alert_me(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 2 times with any arguments
```

An `expect` is very strict. `expect(@at).to receive(:alert_me)` means you expect `@at` to receive `alert_me` *exactly once*. If you expect it to be called twice add `.twice`. See [Receive Counts](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/setting-constraints/receive-counts) for more on how to control that.

But you're not testing that `alert_me` was called, you're mocking it so you can test the error logging. When mocking use [`allow`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/basics/allowing-messages). `allow` can be called any number of times.

```
allow(@at).to receive(:alert_me).and_raise("oops")
```